# Comparar strings en base al orden lexicográfico con C++

Tags: c++

El ejercicio se basa en el orden lexicográfico y consiste en la comparación de dos strings, y con ellos hay que determinar cuál es mayor que el otro lexicográficamente, no en longitud.

Por ejemplo, con las palabras *Tiempo* y *Tiene* respectivamente, se debería imprimir "*El segundo string es mayor*" (Ya que son iguales en las primeras 3 letras pero en el cuarto caracter, *Tiene* le es mayor que a *Tiempo* con 'n' y 'm'), y al revés debería ser "*El primer string es mayor*", lo cual no sucede con mi programa, que arroja para ambos casos "*El primer string es mayor*".

Les dejo mi código para que vean.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string s1, s2;
    bool s1mayor = true;
    bool s2mayor = true;

    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;

    if (s1.length() >= s2.length())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        {
            if (s1[i] > s2[i])
            {
                s1mayor = false;
            }
            else if (s2[i] > s1[i])
            {
                s2mayor = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s1[j] > s2[j])
            {
                s1mayor = false;
            }
            else if (s2[j] > s1[j])
            {
                s2mayor = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (s1mayor == false)
    {
        cout << "El primer string es mayor";
    }
    else if (s2mayor == false)
    {
        cout << "El segundo string es mayor";
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías cambiar el título de la pregunta, ya que se trata de encontrar la cadena de mayor longitud y no la cadena mayor lexicográficamente.

Comment: Si te ha servido marca la respuesta como correcta

Comment: Perdonen gente, me confundí, me refería al string mayor lexicográficamente, no en longitud

Comment: Edita y redacta bien la pregunta para saber que quieres

Comment: Usa [`strncmp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/strncmp.html). Si quieres hacerlo a mano, checa la implementación de esa función para darte una idea

Answer (score 1):

En tu algoritmo falla principalmente que, cuando estableces uno de los dos flags a `false`, no abandonas el bucle. Así tenemos que:

```
T - T -> iguales
i   i -> iguales
e   e -> iguales
m   n -> s1 menor
p   e -> s2 menor
o     -> no evaluas este caso
```

Como ves, el algoritmo llega a la conclusión de que ambas palabras son más pequeñas. La configuración de los `ifs` final determina cual de los dos mensajes se va a mostrar.

```
if (s1.length() >= s2.length())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])
        {
            s1mayor = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (s2[i] > s1[i])
        {
            s2mayor = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!s1mayor && !s2mayor)
      s2mayor = s1.lengt() == s2.length();
}
```

Claro, aquí tenemos un problema semántico y es que estás haciendo uso de lógica un poco extraña:

```
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])
        {
            s1mayor = false;
            break;
        }
```

Es decir, cuando `s1 > s2` pones a false el flag `s1mayor`, ¿Por qué? El que tendrías que poner a false en este caso sería `s2mayor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1, s2;

    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;

    if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        cout << "El primer string es más grande..\n";
    } else if (s2.length() > s1.length()) {
        cout << "El segundo string es más grande..\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Son iguales\n";
    }
}
```

No es necesario que hagas ningún bucle, ni tampoco necesitas variables boleanas para resolver el problema que comentas de ver qué cadena es mayor. El método length() ya te da el tamaño de cada cadena por tanto solo es hacer un par de condicionales comparando ambos tamaños de las cadenas.

Comment: PD: perdón por el formateo del código estoy desde el teléfono móvil